# Python Instantiating SubClasses

Tags: python

I wrote the following code trying to figure out how to instantiate the subclasses within the main class.. I came up with something that doesn't feel right.. at least for me.

Is there something wrong with this type of instancing? Is there a better way to call subclasses?

```
class Family():
  def __init__(self):
    self.Father = self.Father(self)
    self.Mother = self.Mother(self)

  class Father():
    def __init__(self, instance = ''):
      self = instance if instance != '' else self
      print self

    def method(self):
      print "Father Method"

    def fatherMethod(self):
      print "Father Method"


  class Mother():
    def __init__(self, instance = ''):
      self = instance if instance != '' else self
      print self

    def method(self):
      print "Mother Method"

    def motherMethod(self):
      print "Mother Method"



if __name__ == "__main__":
  Family = Family()
  Family.Father.method()
  Family.Mother.method()
```

Comment: This looks weird. Why are you passing self to the inner-class constructors? Please explain what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've defined there are *not* (in Python terminology at least) subclasses - they're inner classes, or nested classes. I'm guessing that this isn't actually what you were trying to achieve, but I'm not sure what you did actually want - but here are my four best guesses:

1. [A subclass](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) is where the class inheriting from another class is called a subclass. To make `father` a subclass of `family`, use the syntax `class Father(Family):`. What you've created here is actually called an Inner Class, not a subclass.
2. When you see something like `Family.Father.method()`, it often means Family is a [module](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) and Father is a class in that module. In Python, `module` basically means `.py file`. A module doesn't have an `__init__` method, but all code at the top level of the module (such as the `if __name__ ...` line) gets executed when a module is imported.
3. Similarly, you could make Family a [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) - which in Python basically means a directory on the filesystem containing an `__init__.py` file. `Father` and `Mother` would then be modules or classes within the package
4. Possibly what you're trying to achieve is declare that an object of type `Family` always has a `Father` object and a `Mother` object. This doesn't require nested classes (in fact, nested classes are a completely bizarre way to do this). Just use:

```
>>> class Mother():
...   def whoami(self):
...     print "I'm a mother"
... 
>>> class Father():
...   def whoami(self):
...     print "I'm a father"
...
>>> class Family():
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.mother = Mother()
...     self.father = Father()
...  
>>> f = Family()
>>> f.father.whoami()
I'm a father
>>> f.mother.whoami()
I'm a mother
>>>
```

Comment: I'm curious - which of these were you aiming for?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this code does not *feel* right. My questions would be ..

- What are you trying to achieve? There is not need to define `Father` and `Mother` inside `Family`, they could be defined outside `Family` and aggregated into it. (Is it the fact, that `Father` and `Mother` should not be accessed outside of a `Family`? Python has no visibility modifiers, e.g. because of a principle that goes: 'we are all grown-up here', meaning that developers should be responsible and assume responsible handling of code ...)
- Do you really need something like `Class.Class.method`? Beside the fact, that method lookups are a little costly, these kind of chains may indicate a *wrong axis*, meaning you're trying to take hold of functionality from a not very clearly designed point (sorry for being so blurry here.)